# How to be a verified publisher?

Tags: verify, publisher

I wrote an app and I want to sell it online, so I uploaded it to my website and tried to download and run it as a test, but a window appeared, it said : "The publisher could not be verified. Are you sure you want to run this software ?", and it also said : "Publisher : Unknown Publisher". It's actually a self-signed Java jar file wrapped into an exe file, I self-signed it with Netbeans6.7.

I wonder what should I do to be a "known" publisher ?

Frank

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to sign the EXE with a code signing certificate from a trusted root certification authority.

http://www.thawte.com/code-signing/

https://www.verisign.com/code-signing/

You'll find more CAs with a simple [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=code+signing+certificate).

Keep in mind, even though this is a Java JAR, the dialog you're seeing is from Windows complaining about the EXE being unsigned.  You'll need a MS Authenticode signing certificate to sign the EXE.  I'm not too familiar with Java, so you may or may not need a certificate to sign the JAR as well.  (Note a self-signed certificate will **never** be recognized as fully Trusted and Valid on any computer other than your own.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to sign it with an approved signing certificate an example is at 
http://codesigning.ksoftware.net