# Java Virtual Machine Launcher Error: Invalid or Corrupt Jar file

Tags: java, windows, certificate, exe, signed

I am creating a ***jar*** file using netbeans. Then I create ***exe*** of this jar file using [lanch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). When I run this ***exe*** file on my computer it's run fine But When I run this ***exe*** on some other computer it gives me warning

**The publisher could not be verified. Are you want to run this software**

When click on Run the exe file runs fine.

[image]

I remove that warning by adding certificate to my exe file using **signtool.exe** which comes with **windows sdk**. and it successfully added certificate to my **exe file**.

But now when I run my exe file it gives me error

"***Java Virtual Machine Launcher 
Error: Invalid or Corrupt Jar file***"

[image]

Plz Help me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to be a verified publisher?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660814/how-to-be-a-verified-publisher)

Answer (score 2):

This warning gets thrown because your application has not been signed. You didn't see the error on your local machine because you never transmitted the application. You saw it on some other machine presumably because you uploaded it somewhere then downloaded it to the other machine.

Checkout this other question for more info: [Signing a Windows EXE file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file)

Comment: thanks dzylich. I have a certificate with .pfx extention. but I don;t know how to install that certificate to my exe file.

Comment: I add the certificate to my exe. and it is successfully added but when I run that exe file I gives an error "Java Virtual Machine Launcher  Error: Invalid or Corrupt jar file"

Comment: Hey @UsmanAli, I'm not sure what's causing that error. I am not familiar enough with signing a Java package specifically to know what could cause that.

Comment: Thanks for help @dzylich

Comment: i have sign in by ksign but it still showing error. any other though?

Answer (score 1):

EXE SIGNER FOR JAR WRAPPED INSIDE A EXE USING LAUNCH4J:

1.CERTIFICATION CREATION IS SAME AS NORMAL EXE SIGNER.

```
makecert -r -pe -ss MyCertStore -n "CN=MyTestCert" MyTestCert.cer
```

(NOTE:Import this certificate to Trusted certificate part in certmgr.msc in windows.)

Then only It won’t show unknown publisher at local system.

**TO VERIFY:**

In windows ,Just type `certmgr.msc` in start window search box, `certmgr.msc` will prompt on screen, open that and then check whether certificate is successfully imported in Trusted certificate part.)

2.SIGN IN EXE USING SIGNTOOL AND SIGN4J:

```
sign4j signtool sign /s MyCertStore /n MyTestCert  "sample.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

use sign4j to verify launch4j exe..
It avoid jar corruption..

**sign4j signtool sign /s MyCertStore /n My_cert sample.exe**

verify this link.. It will help you..
[Sign a launch4j executable in ant with sign4j and jsign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325009/sign-a-launch4j-executable-in-ant-with-sign4j-and-jsign)

Comment: sign4j is a tool used in launch4j for signing exe.

Comment: It is present inside a lauch4j folder.
For Detailed Steps:
Verify this blog: